# Failed to parse the cube name from the query

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence

I have created a new dataset for the SSRS report, whed I execute the query on the dataset I get this error:

[errorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AaGs.png)

I don't know why this error appears knowing that I used the same in another report and I can execute it without getting a problem.

Comment: That's not a complete MDX statement. The error message is letting you know that there's no `FROM` clause in the query. It would be like in SQL saying `SELECT MyColumn` ... from where?